# Curious Question with bijectivity and measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $(\Omega_1, \mathcal{A}_1)$, $(\Omega_2, \mathcal{A}_2)$ and $(\Omega_3, \mathcal{A}_3)$ are measurable spaces. Suppose that $f: \Omega_1 \to \Omega_2$ is a bijective measurable map and $g: \Omega_2 \to \Omega_3$ is a bijective measurable map. Does that mean that $|\mathcal{A}_1| = |\mathcal{A}_2| = |\mathcal{A}_3|$?

Comment: What happens if $(\Omega_3, \mathcal{A}_3) \neq (\Omega_2, \mathcal{A}_2)$

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I dont see any green pen, but thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Omega_1 = \Omega_2 = \Omega_3 = \mathbb{R}$, and let $\mathcal{A}_1 = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, $\mathcal{A}_2 = \{ \emptyset, A, A^\complement, \mathbb{R}\}$, and $\mathcal{A}_3 = \{ \emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}$ for some non-empty $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ where $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Then let $f = g = \iota$, the identity map.

I think it's clear that $f$ and $g$ are measurable, but the cardinalities of the $\sigma$-algebras are unequal.

Comment: Thanks! However, what if $\Omega_i \neq \Omega_j$, where $i \neq j$ and $i, j, \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Let $\Omega_1 = \mathbb{R}$, $\Omega_2 = \mathbb{R}^+$, and let $\Omega_3 = (0, 1)$. You can probably fiddle with the functions to make it work.